# Closing specific form using a method in C#

Tags: c#, forms, methods

Hi I have some forms in my project and I want to do a method that closed one of them.
The method is:

```
public static void close_form (Form frm)
{
    frm.Close();
}
```

And I use it this way:

```
public partial class myForm : Form
{
   close_form(myForm);
}
```

but when I want to run the application I get error:
`myForm` is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to `close` the form without using `this.close()`?

Comment: Why are you avoiding calling the `Close` method directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing type of the form i.e. `myForm`  you need to pass object of type, you can pass [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

```
public partial class myForm : Form
{
   close_form(this);
}
```

Here `myForm` is new type that inherits from `Form` type and is not instance of your current form. The keyword `this` represents the current instance of class you can pass that to `close_form` you can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx).

There is *no* reason for closing form by calling a function if function just have only one statement to close the form unless you are doing this for learning or you could have some reason for closing forms through function like logging some information like closing form name and time etc. You simple call `this.Close` instead of calling `close_form` and passing current form to it.

Comment: Of course, it's entirely unclear why this is superior to `this.Close()`.

Comment: You are right apparently there is no reason for closing form that way instead of using this.Close but IMO close_form is a static method and could be called from other classes / forms and could do some common process like logging.